# Low level codes for sending keys regardless of keyboard format? (QWERTY, AZERTY, etc) Python

Tags: python, keyboard, sendkeys, qwerty

My question is how do I use a module like `keyboard.write()` or  `shell.sendkeys()` to send keystrokes that will be recognized by ALL versions of keyboards. Is there a base level dictionary so to speak that maps every key to a code, regardless of what keyboard format you use?  (QWERTY, AZERTY, QWERTZ etc) It seems that all the letter keys work through different keyboard formats, but numbers and some special keys do not. For example there is no grave key (`) on AZERTY keyboards like there is on QWERTY.  You have to press " Alt Gr + è" to access grave key on AZERTY.... is there some base level codes for every key?

I have tried chr() which does not translate to other keyboard formats.

Comment: Those codes are called "scan codes", but I don't know about any Python utility or library working with them. They are really very close to hardware, formerly keyboard serial port, now USB ports (and HID devices).

Comment: Thanks for the reply- I figured there might not be a way.  I am making a demo player for a video game, and it has to write to console of the game.  Alot of people that play are in eu with different layouts.  Workaround is creating a big dictionary for each layout! lol